# MySQL insertion with all values at once

Tags: mysql, insert

I was doing an `INSERT INTO TABLE(...,...,...,...,...) VALUES(...,...,...,`
When I closed by mistake my MySQL Query Browser. The table has too many columns, so I was wondering, is there a command that you don't need to type all names of the columns table?

If so, how?

Comment: See link below http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_insert.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THere is

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES(...,...,...)
```

You just need to specify ALL fields in EXACTLY same sequence as they're in table definition.

For `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, or for columns where you want to use `DEFAULT` value as defined in table definition (also `TIMESTAMP`s) use `null` as a value.

Comment: what if is there a primary key that is autoincrement? I just skip it right?

Comment: Use NULL as the value for PK/AutoIncrement keys

Comment: Yup: null it is. Also use null for any column that you want the default value as defined in table definition.

Answer (score 1):

If you are insterting into **all** the columns you can write:

```
 insert into tablename values(...,...,etc.)
```

Comment: This is the way to do it, however, I would suggest to the person who asked the question not to do it this way. If your table schema changes, you will have to rewrite any insert statement using this method.

Comment: @GateKiller, yeah I agree. It doesn't sound like the OP is doing it from code though.